# This number is prime & secure?

Tags: java, primes

I need to create a 2048bits prime number.

I have used this code.

```
SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
int certainty = 100000000;
BigInteger p = new BigInteger(2048, certainty, rnd);
```

This number is prime & secure ?

If the wrong way, what should I do ?

If you let me know, I'm very grateful to you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This number is *probably* prime. There are ways of checking if it is indeed prime, but this does not do it. On another note, I suggest using `BigInteger.probablePrime(int bitLength, Random rnd)` with [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#probablePrime%28int,%20java.util.Random%29) to get rid of the certainty value.

As to whether or not it is *secure*, well that entirely depends on your definition of secure, however the SecureRandom class is compliant with various cryptographic standards, so you should be good in that regard.